# Defining a DCG in Prolog for bit strings

Tags: prolog, dcg

Ahead of our Prolog exam next week, our lecturer has provided us with a number of practice questions, but I'm stumped for the following. Can anyone help?

> For each integer n > 0,
>
> let Ln := {s ∈ {0, 1}+ | s ends in a string from 1(0 + 1)n−1}
>
> be the set of bit-strings whose n-th to the last bit is 1. That is, Ln
> is described by the regular expression
>
> (0 + 1)∗1(0 + 1)n−1.
>
> Define a DCG for the 3-ary predicate s/3 such that s(n,s,[]) is true
> exactly if s encodes a string in Ln.

Comment: Can you write a DCG that describes the same language as the regular expression `(0+1)`? Can you write one for `(0+1)*`? Show us what you tried, which parts you can do, and which part you need help with.

Comment: @IsabelleNewbie after a long time, I have a solution ... post Y/N?

Answer (score 1):

```
% ---
% It turns out we need these
% ---

% "any(N,gen)" generates/accepts any bitstring of KNOWN length N
% The order of clauses is unimportant!

any(N,gen) --> { N > 0 }, ( `0` ; `1` ), { Nm is N-1 }, any(Nm,gen).
any(0,gen) --> [].

% "any(N,genfree)" generates/accepts any bitstring of ARBITRARY length N
% The clause for [] must be first and the 01 arbitrary choice must come
% after the recursion.

any(0,genfree) --> [].
any(N,genfree) --> any(Nm,genfree), ( `0` ; `1` ), { N is Nm+1 }.

% ---
% Run the DCG grammer in various modes
% ---

% When generating, use 'x' instead of '1' to make the special '1' visible
% When generating with N unstated we need to make sure we "go to infinity"
% in an equitable manner. Going to infinity for the overall length and 
% dividing that length up between "any" suffix and "any" prefix sounds fair!

my_language(N,gen)     --> any(_,genfree), `1`, any(N,gen).
my_language(N,genfree) --> { between(0,inf,L), between(0,L,N), Prefix is L-N }, any(Prefix,gen), `1`, any(N,gen).

% Pretending the overall length of the bitstring is unknown is quixotic.
% First it's inefficient and then it's awkward to avoid guessing longer
% and longer prefixes that are longer than the string overall and sink
% into the backtracking tarpit. Much better to use the overall bitstring 
% length!

my_language(N,accept,L)     --> { M is L-N-1 }, any(M,gen), `1`, any(N,gen).
my_language(N,acceptfree,L) --> { Lm is L-1, between(0,Lm,N), M is L-N-1 }, any(M,gen), `1`, any(N,gen).

% ===
% Printing
% ===

explain(Text,Bits,N) :-
  atom_chars(Bits,Chars),
  length(Suffix,N),
  append([Prefix,[X],Suffix],Chars),
  format("~s [~s][~s][~s]~n",[Text,Prefix,[X],Suffix]).

% ===
% Call these. In all cases, the remainder must be the empty string because
% we use phrase/2, which is the same as phrase/3 with emtpy remainder
% ===

% accept Bits, with N unstated, and using the overall length of Bits

lang(Bits,N) :-
  var(N),nonvar(Bits),
  !,
  atom_codes(Bits,Codes),
  length(Codes,L),  
  format("Accepting ~q of length ~q, suffix length unstated~n",[Bits,L]),
  phrase(my_language(N,acceptfree,L),Codes),
  explain("Found",Bits,N).

% accept Bits, with N stated, and using the overall length of Bits

lang(Bits,N) :-
  nonvar(N),nonvar(Bits),
  !,
  atom_codes(Bits,Codes),
  length(Codes,L),
  format("Accepting ~q of length ~q, need suffix of length ~q~n",[Bits,L,N]),
  phrase(my_language(N,accept,L),Codes),
  explain("Found",Bits,N).

% generate Bits, with N unstated (and thus proposable by Prolog)
   
lang(Bits,N) :- 
   var(N),var(Bits),
   !,
   format("Generating phrases, nothing stated~n",[]),
   phrase(my_language(N,genfree),Codes), 
   atom_codes(Bits,Codes),
   explain("Generated",Bits,N).

% generate Bits, with N stated

lang(Bits,N) :- 
   integer(N),var(Bits),
   !,
   format("Generating phrases, need suffix of length ~q~n",[N]),
   phrase(my_language(N,gen),Codes),
   atom_codes(Bits,Codes),
   explain("Generated",Bits,N).
```

And so:

**We can accept bitstrings**

...finding a suffix length:

```
?- lang('0101000100100001',_).
Accepting '0101000100100001' of length 16, suffix length unstated
Found [010100010010000][1][]
true ;
Found [0101000100][1][00001]
true ;
Found [0101000][1][00100001]
true ;
Found [010][1][000100100001]
true ;
Found [0][1][01000100100001]
true ;
false.
```

...stating a suffix length:

```
?- lang('0101000100100001',2).
Accepting '0101000100100001' of length 16, need suffix of length 2
false.

?- lang('0101000100100001',5).
Accepting '0101000100100001' of length 16, need suffix of length 5
Found [0101000100][1][00001]
true ;
false.
```

**We can generate (longer and longer) bitstrings**

...stating a suffix length:

```
?- lang(X,2).
Generating phrases, need suffix of length 2
Generated [][1][00]
X = '100' ;
Generated [][1][01]
X = '101' ;
Generated [][1][10]
X = '110' ;
Generated [][1][11]
X = '111' ;
Generated [0][1][00]
X = '0100' ;
Generated [0][1][01]
X = '0101' ;
Generated [0][1][10]
X = '0110' ;
Generated [0][1][11]
X = '0111' ;
Generated [1][1][00]
X = '1100' ;
Generated [1][1][01]
X = '1101' ;
Generated [1][1][10]
X = '1110' ;
Generated [1][1][11]
X = '1111' ;
Generated [00][1][00]
X = '00100' 
...
```

...leaving the suffix length free and letting Prolog propose one:

```
?- lang(X,N).
Generating phrases, nothing stated
Generated [][1][]
X = '1',
N = 0 ;
Generated [0][1][]
X = '01',
N = 0 ;
Generated [1][1][]
X = '11',
N = 0 ;
Generated [][1][0]
X = '10',
N = 1 ;
Generated [][1][1]
X = '11',
N = 1 ;
Generated [00][1][]
X = '001',
N = 0 ;
Generated [01][1][]
X = '011',
N = 0 ;
Generated [10][1][]
X = '101',
N = 0 ;
Generated [11][1][]
X = '111',
N = 0
```

Comment: What's wrong with something like this? `language(N) --> any01, [1], { N1 #= N - 1 }, { N1 #>= 0 }, n01(N1).
a01 --> [0] | [1].
any01 --> [] | a01, any01.
n01(0) --> [].
n01(N) --> a01, { N1 #= N - 1 }, { N1 #>= 0 }, n01(N1).`
Use as `length(String, Length), phrase(language(N), String)` for fair generation.

Comment: @IsabelleNewbie This exhibits the problem I ran into: When generating, the prefix only contains '0'. I then got frustrated with the CLP(FD) approach and just went with case-based reasoning.

Comment: Like I wrote, it generates all prefixes if you force grouping by list length by using `length(String, Length)` before the `phrase`.

Comment: @IsabelleNewbie Ahh! I see. Very ingenious.